# I am parsing a XML file using libxmljs and .get() always returns the first child

Tags: javascript, node.js, libxml-js

I have been looking at this code for hours and I can't make it work, and I don't know why.

```
var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
var xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
       '<root>' +
           '<child foo="bar">' +
               '<grandchild>First Child</grandchild>' +
           '</child>' +
           '<child foo="bar">' +
               '<grandchild>Second child</grandchild>' +
           '</child>' +
           '<child foo="bar">' +
               '<grandchild>Third Child</grandchild>' +
           '</child>' +
           '<sibling>with content!</sibling>' +
       '</root>';

var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml);

var childs = xmlDoc.find('//child');

for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++)
  console.log(childs[i].get('//grandchild').text());
```

What I expect is to get in console

First Child
Second Child
Third Child

But what I got is:

First Child
First Child
First Child

I have discovered that .get('//grandchild') returns all grandchilds in the code, despite it being called from just a node. I can't use it with an index because in my actual XML every node can have differents childs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want relative XPaths.

```
for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++)
  console.log(childs[i].get('.//grandchild').text()); 
//---------------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const transform = require("camaro")
const xml =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
       '<root>' +
           '<child foo="bar">' +
               '<grandchild>First Child</grandchild>' +
           '</child>' +
           '<child foo="bar">' +
               '<grandchild>Second child</grandchild>' +
           '</child>' +
           '<child foo="bar">' +
               '<grandchild>Third Child</grandchild>' +
           '</child>' +
           '<sibling>with content!</sibling>' +
       '</root>';

const { grandchildren } = transform(xml, {
    grandchildren: ['//grandchild', '.']
})

for (let i = 0; i < grandchildren.length; i++) {
    console.log(grandchildren[i])
}
```

Output

```
// First Child
// Second child
// Third Child
```